# Vertex for quartic interaction of complex scalar multiplet

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams

Since I'm new to QFT and I tend to do a lot of errors during calculations, I would like you to tell me if I got the four-point vertex of the quartic interaction with a multiplet of complex scalar fields right:

$$ L = (\partial_\mu \Phi)^\dagger (\partial^\mu\Phi) - m^2\Phi^\dagger\Phi-\lambda(\Phi^\dagger\Phi)(\Phi^\dagger\Phi),$$

where $\Phi= (\phi_1,\ldots,\phi_N)$ and $\phi_i$ are complex scalar fields. I have

$$-2i\lambda ( \delta^{ik}\delta^{jh} + \delta^{ih}\delta^{jk}),$$

where $i,j$ are the indices of the two $\Phi^\dagger$, while $k,h$ are the indices of the two $\Phi$.
Is it correct?

Comment: This is a legitimate technical question of somebody who wants to understant the interactions of a scalar field, so can the reviewers who are not interesred in QFT at a technical level please leave it alone?